# display lighthouse results in azure pipeline and fail build on certain lighthouse conditions

Tags: azure-pipelines, lighthouse

I am able to run the following bash script that uses the dockerhub lighthouse image to run some tests on a url:

```
docker run --rm --name lighthouse -it \
  -v $PWD/test-results/lighthouse:/home/chrome/reports \
  --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN femtopixel/google-lighthouse \
  $full_url \
  --output html \
  --output json
```

I've got a volume for the results and there are results json and html files created.

How would I use these results to fail ci.  I'm sure I can parse the json but how would I then fail the build if needs be.

Also, is it possible for me to show the results in a tab?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can execute the bash script successfully, you must by executing other tasks to make the build failed, e.g **Powershell** task.

Specified the **[Output variables](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/master/docs/preview/outputvariable.md)** of Bash Script task to pass one variable to the next task--Powershell. And in Powershell, get and verify this variable value, if equals, execute the script to let it failed.

For show result in tab, I'm afraid that there's no such feature to achieve this.